# How to write haml in case of using only opening html tag in if&else constrruction

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, haml, erb

I have perfect working ERB partial, it look's like:

```
<% if error_tag.present? %>
 <div class="form-group has-error">
<% else %>
 <div class="form-group">
<% end %> 
 <div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="<%= picture_tag %>"></i></div>
  <%= cycle_tag.text_field (fildname_tag), class: 'form-control', placeholder: placeholder_tag %>
 </div> <!--input-group-->
<ul> 
 <% if error_tag.present? %>
  <% error_tag.each do |msg| %>
   <li>Field <%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
</ul>
</div> <!--form-group or form-group has-error-->
```

Now I'm trying to make the equivalent code in HAML. In case of ERB, in the first IF condition I'm operating only with opening div tag. I made HAML, and it's working, but it look's like not DRY.
Here it is:

```
- if error_tag.present? 
    .form-group.has-error
        .input-group
            .input-group-addon
                %i{:class => picture_tag}       
            = cycle_tag.text_field fildname_tag, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => placeholder_tag
        %ul
            - if error_tag.present?
                - error_tag.each do |msg|
                    %li 
                        Field 
                        = msg
- else 
    .form-group
        .input-group    
            .input-group-addon
                %i{:class => picture_tag}       
            = cycle_tag.text_field fildname_tag, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => placeholder_tag
```

Can you help me to make really DRY equivalent my ERB partial. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s only the `has-error` class that is conditional, so move the check into the attributes like this:

```
.form-group{:class => ('has-error' if error_tag.present?) }
  .input-group
    .input-group-addon
      %i{:class => picture_tag}       
    = cycle_tag.text_field fildname_tag, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => placeholder_tag
  %ul
    - if error_tag.present?
      - error_tag.each do |msg|
        %li Field #{msg}
```

If there is no error then `('has-error' if error_tag.present?)` will evaluate to `nil` and Haml will just use `form-group` as the class. If there is an error Haml will combine the two strings to make the class attribute.